# Error: EACCES: permission denied when running : npm install -g json-server , ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json

i'm trying to run this command inside vscode for React project

```
npm install -g json-server
```

then i get this error :

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/bin.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/json-server
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/bin.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/json-server'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/bin.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/json-server'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/bin.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/json-server'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/ecod/.npm/_logs/2023-07-30T02_04_59_837Z-debug-0.log
```

i have tried to solve with running some cmd that found on the internet but not working. still same problem

Comment: First, don't copy and paste random commands from the internet if you're not sure what they do. Secondly, most likely at some point you've used npm as root. This should almost never be necessary, but you can (probably) fix this by using `sudo npm i -g json-server`. You could also take ownership of `/usr/local`, but it looks like you're on Mac so you might have to disable SIP to make that work. The best option is to just not use system directories, meaning to [change your npm prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/folders).